# Redirecionar para um controller em outra Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Procurei uma solução para isso mas não consegui, estou tentando redirecionar erros de sessão para o login,  minha aplicação fica dentro de uma pasta chamada `Areas` e quando viu redirecionar algo para ele eu redireciono assim :

```
  <li><a  href="@Url.Action("Enviadas", "Mensagem", new {PaginaAtual = 0, area = "Lojista" })"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Enviadas</a></li>
```

Mas depois que estou dentro dela preciso redirecionar para o login , que esta na pasta Controllers fora da pasta areas , (Controller e Areas estão no mesmo nivel)

Eu estou tentando redirecionar assim :

```
if (loja == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new {area = "~/Controllers" });
}
```

Mas esta dando problema de rota, se alguém souber me responde ficarei grato.

EDIT :  No Momento que eu tento redirecionar eu estou no Controller da DashBoard que fica em `~/Areas/Lojista/Dashboard` , e eu preciso redirecionar para o login , que fica fora de Areas, que seria `~/Login`     Neste caso o login esta na pasta de controllers normal do ASP.net e o restante esta na `~/Areas/Lojista`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas passe o parâmetro area vazio. Isso vai fazer com que o Controller seja procurado na area raiz.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login", new {area = "" });
```